# Why long form of state in shipping address is not accepted?

Tags: paypal

I am using PayPal ExpressCheckout SOAP API.
I found that when I passed shipping address to PayPal as

```
Street1="XXX actual address masked XXX"
CityName="Las Vegas"
StateOrProvince="Nevada"
PostalCode="89121"
Country=CountryCodeType.US
AddressStatus=AddressStatusCodeType.Confirmed
AddressStatusSpecified = true
CountrySpecified = true
```

PayPal returned the error "Error in payment details. A match of the Shipping Address City, State, and Postal Code failed."

However it can pass through when 
    StateOrProvince="NV"

Is it true that PayPal must accept US State in short form only?  Is there any way that it can accept both long and short forms?

Regards
Edwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, PayPal only accepts the 2-character abbreviation for US state names.

Comment: Hi PayPal, you are going a great job.  Don't you have the resources to translate the states for us when you are making money from our transactions?

Comment: I'm going into the realm of speculation here, but I believe the reason is probably twofold -- a) some features, like eBay shipping, probably require the 2-character state codes, and b) some merchants (probably large ones) probably wouldn't appreciate us altering the address they sent us, even if it is just to translate it from the full name down to the abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the same name in both fields State and City, this error also occurs.

I get this problem using PayPal Express checkout at Shopify, and solve simply typing New York City in the City field, instead just New York (the same as the State).

I hope it helps.